# Django unhandle exceptions - Handler for that?

Tags: django

As per django's documentation - if there are any unhandled exceptions django sends an email to ADMINS email list : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/error-reporting/

For any unhandled exceptions - is there any way one can add a wrapper around it ?

The goal is : instead of sending an email - i want to handle the exception, do some parsing, and add it into the DB and/or log the info.

If folks can nudge me in the right direction, would really appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, so I'm not sure if there are cases it doesn't cover, but I think this is what `process_exception` middleware is for (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception).

Comment: Thats a good direction. I was thinking of writing a middleware anyways.